# Paypal express button line items not showing up

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I'm using the new 2019 paypal sdk with React and I'm trying to create an order with 2 line items. When I create an order, I'm able to get the correct total inside paypal and complete a transaction, but on the test users receipt, it just shows the total for 25.99 and no line items. I'm following v2 of their api instructions but no items are showing up.

```
        purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
                currency_code: 'USD',
                value: '25.99',
                breakdown: {
                    item_total: { value: '25.99', currency_code: 'USD' }
                }
            }
        }],
        items: [
            {
                name: 'Watercolor texture kit Vol. 1',
                unit_amount: {
                    value: '16.00',
                    currency_code: 'USD'
                },
                quantity: '1',
                description: 'test desc',
                sku: '222'
            },
            {
                name: 'Skinny jeans',
                unit_amount: {
                    currency_code: 'USD',
                    value: '9.99'
                },
                quantity: '1',
                description: 'test desc',
                sku: '30'
            }
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, I had a similar problem. I think the items need to be inside the purchase_units. I also found to work that I need to include the descriptors in quotes - the API docs don't specify this though.

Comment: IS `purchase_units`part of the paypal required fields?

Comment: @Nelles From what I gather from the docs `purchase_units` is the main parameter that sends to order details to paypal via the smart button, and is required.

Comment: I ended up having to use the most recent version of the paypal api to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'm using to make it work:

```
<script id='paypal-js' src={`https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${PaypalKey}&disable-funding=credit,card&commit=true&merchant-id=${PaypalMerchantId}&locale=en_US&integration-date=2019-11-07`}/>
```

Integration date makes paypal use different versions of the api depending on the date.

```
purchase_units: [{
    amount: {
     currency_code: currency,
     value: cart.totalPrice,
     breakdown: {
        item_total: { 
         value: cart.totalPrice, 
         currency_code: currency 
        }
     }
    },
    invoice_id: Math.random().toString(36).substring(14),
    items: getPaypalFormatItems(cart, products),
    soft_descriptor: 'Digital Purchase', // appears on CC statement
    description: 'Paypal payment'
}],
application_context: {
    brand_name: 'Every-Tuesday',
    shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING',
    user_action: 'PAY_NOW'
}
```